# Highcharts seriesname under each other

Tags: highcharts

I want to be able to put all the seriesname under each other. Currently 2 appear next to each other.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oioQ8.png)

The only way to get them under each other is by adding more characters. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve vertical-align for legend items, use `legend.align` option set to `vertical`,

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wfduk38x/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.align